# MongoDB slice behavior on array within an array within $addFields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following mongo pipeline:

```
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'zones', 
      'localField': 'zones.zoneID', 
      'foreignField': 'zoneID', 
      'as': 'zone'
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'zone.assistantZoneContacts': {
        '$slice': [
          {
            '$ifNull': [
              '$zone.zoneContacts', [
                {
                  'userID': null
                }
              ]
            ]
          }, 1, 100
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'cz': {
        '$size': [
          '$zone.assistantZoneContacts'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Where the top level 'zones' property is an array of { zoneID: the zone id }. The lookup of the zone works fine, but the $addFields does not appear to return any data (i.e. the zone.assistantZoneContacts is always an empty array) although the cz value always shows a value of 1.

When I run the same $addFields expression on the the 'zones' collection directly (i.e. the collection that was used as the target for the lookup), it works without a problem.

$unwind'ing is not an option, because I want a single top level document (not multiple if there is more than one zone and/or zone contact). It is being used simply as a filter for the top level document.

Is this possible without resorting to more programmatic approaches (i.e. filtering through the data brought down to the app server)? I would prefer to handle this completely through MQL.

An example of what a fragment of the document in the collection may look like is:

```
{
   ...
   zones: [
     {
       zoneID: 1,
     }
   ]
   ...
}
```

The corresponding zones collection would have the following content:

```
{
   zoneID: 1,
   ...
   zoneContacts: [
     {
       userID: X
     },
     { 
       userID: y
     }
   ]
   ...
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to add an example of what 1 doc looks like post-lookup and 1 that shows your desired output?   I sense there is an issue with `zone` coming out of `lookup` as an array but is being treated as a single object in `addFields`

Comment: Assuming the 'zoneContacts' field in each zone is an array of contact objects, what exactly is the intent?  Without unwinding you'll probably end up with an array of arrays, and the 'assistantZoneContacts' of each element of 'zone' will be identical.

Comment: Joe, yes I ended up with an array of arrays (which is fine). However, I need to re-associate them with their respective object so they may be selected by their corresponding zoneID (i.e. the arrays of objects need to be merged based on their ordinal position within their arrays).